# Why postfixed has higher precedence than prefixed?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Case 1:

```
int i = 10;
int j = i++;
```

Here, first the value of i is assigned to j and than i is increased by 1.

Case 2:

```
int i = 10;
int j = ++i;
```

Here, first i is increased by 1 and than it is assigned to j.

So, If the operation of increment is done first in the prefixed form, then why postfixed has higher precedence than prefixed?

Comment: The precedence of an operation is loosely related to the nature of the operation itself.

Comment: prefixed = increment and return, postfixed return and increment

Comment: Um.. not sure why *that* duplicate...

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I can change it to a better one if you know of one :)

Comment: Precedence is an independent concept of evaluation order. Evaluation order is constrained by dependencies: an operation requiring its input operands to be evaluated before it can produce output. Given `a * (b + c)`, we can evaluate `a`, `b` and `c` before performing a single arithmetic operation, and the same holds true of `a * b + c`.

Comment: All precedence does is group operators with operands - it does not affect the order in which operations are evaluated.  For example, *precedence* dictates that `++b[i]` is *parsed* as `++(b[i])` - it has nothing to do with the order in which the subexpressions are evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with precedence.(here) In pre-increment the value that is assigned is the value before the side effect takes place.
For pre increment it will be the value after the side effect.

```
int i = 10;
int j = i++;
```

Before incrementing value of `i` is 10. So `j=10` after these 2 statements are executed.

```
int i = 10;
int j = ++i;
```

Here the value will be 11. because incremenet is done first and then it is assigned.

Comment: I guess the question, if we clean all of the noise around, is just "why post increment has a higher precedence than pre-increment". And I would say - for a convenience of writing some common constructs.

Comment: @EugeneSh..: But the question context is completely different isn't it?

Comment: It is. Which gives me a strong urge to close it.

Comment: @StephanLechner.: Otherway yes...pre - post wriitng mess up

Answer (score 0):

Linux `manual` page of `operator` define as `same priority` for both pre/post `increment`.

```
! ~ ++ -- + - (type) * & sizeof      right to left
```

post increment rule is first assigned and then increment

```
int j = i++;// here first whatever i value is there that will be assigned to j
```

Pre increment rule is first increment and then assign

```
int j = ++i;//++i itself will change i value & then modfied value will assign to j.
```

for e.g consider below example

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int x = 10;
        int *p = &x;// assume p holds 0x100
        printf("x = %d *p = %d p = %p\n",x,*p,p);
        ++*p++;
        /** in above statement ++ and * having same precedence,then you should check assocaitivity which is R to L
          So start solving from Right to Left, whichever operator came first , solve that one first 
          first *p++ came , again solve p++ first, which is post increment,so address will be same 
         *0x100  means = 10
         now ++10 means = 11
         **/
        printf("x = %d *p = %d p = %p\n",x,*p,p);
}
```

Comment: that's incorrect. Here is the correct precedence table: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: yes true but what's the difference b/w both ? what ever operator I mentioned in one line all are having same priority or priority 1 according to link provided by you. Associativity is right to left, start from right to left, what comes first that having highest priority among all in precedence 1.

Comment: The difference is when you do something like `++*p++`.

Comment: I have no doubt in that. Both * and ++ having same priority So starts from Right to left, so first *p++ will be performed.

Comment: I see what you mean. Will try to think of a counter-example (if there is any :) )

Comment: Sorry boss My intention is correct only, in hurry I wrote priority in comments it should be precedence.